# PyQt5.QtWebEngine not displaying any webpages

Tags: python, browser, pyqt5

I'm trying to build a simple web browser using python, but the module I'm using (PyQt5.QtWebEngine) isn't working properly. It doesn't display the websites properly. This is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import * 
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl('https://17sunny.netlify.app'))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
        self.showMaximized()
        navbar = QToolBar()
        self.addToolBar(navbar)
        back_btn = QAction('  BACK  ',self)
        back_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.back)
        navbar.addAction(back_btn)
        forward_btn = QAction(' FORWARD ',self)
        forward_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.forward)
        navbar.addAction(forward_btn)
        refresh_btn = QAction('  REFRESH  ',self)
        refresh_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.reload)
        navbar.addAction(refresh_btn)
        home_btn = QAction('  HOME  ',self)
        home_btn.triggered.connect(self.navigate_home)
        navbar.addAction(home_btn)
        self.url_bar = QLineEdit()
        self.url_bar.returnPressed.connect(self.navigate_to_url)
        navbar.addWidget(self.url_bar)
        self.browser.urlChanged.connect(self.update_url)
    def navigate_home(self):
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl('https://google.com'))
    def navigate_to_url(self):
        url = self.url_bar.text()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl(url))
    def update_url(self, q):
        self.url_bar.setText(q.toString())
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
QApplication.setApplicationName('Browser')
window = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

While the application itself loads, none of the webpages do. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling pyqt5, but it didn't work. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: There's quite a difference between "doesn't display the websites properly" and "none of the webpages load". I tested your code and works as expected. Have you tried other and more common websites? Are you behind a proxy/vpn or do you require some kind of authorization to browse the web? Are you in a country that blocks access to some websites? Did you try the code from another computer?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm currently using Ubuntu 22.04. I don't have a vpn/proxy enabled. I've tried websites like google, bing, amzon, etc. I haven't tried it on a different computer but I will try soon and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Also run the program in a terminal and see if it provides some debug about issues with rendering or anything else.

Comment: I decided to try my code on a different operating system, this time trying it on Linux mint 21. Unfortunately, it is still not working.

Comment: Did you run the program in a terminal? Did you get any output? Also, are you using virtualization?

Comment: I ran the program through the terminal and didn't get any errors. I don't know what virtualization is though.